# Retrieving IOI Data From Bloomberg

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

I'm trying to pull real time indication of interest data out of bloomberg and into excel. I cannot find a way to do it via the Excel API so I am considering two options:

1. Some messy VBA API calls to try and pull it out.
2. Taking control of the bloomberg gui using VBA and opening the page.

Does anyone know if either of these are even possible? I can see the latter working with some real serious bodge work with the windows functions and sendkeys but idealy there will be a propper way hidden amongst the many VB libraries.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this question and answer help?  [Bloomberg data doesn't populate until Excel VBA macro finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8669845/973283)

Comment: Have you tried asking Bloomberg? I believe they have an API you could leverage.

Comment: The Bloomberg VBA support I have had from them so far has been fairly useless. IOI data cannot be pulled out using the Excel API from what I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ends up searching this - I ended up using VBA to control the main Bloomberg Terminal. The below takes the screen no to change and the command to pass to the terminal. It is reading the ticker from the active cell.

```
Private Sub Change_Screen(ScreenNo As Byte, QueryString As String)

    Dim Blp As Long

    'Establish connection with terminal via add-in.
    Blp = DDEInitiate("winblp", "bbk")

    'Call add in - make the gui go to the IOI page for security currently selected using the screen select.
    Call DDEExecute(Blp, "<blp-" & ScreenNo - 1 & ">" & ActiveCell.Text & "<equity>" & QueryString & "<GO>")

    'Kill terminal connection.
    Call DDETerminate(Blp)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find this data through the API or `FLDS` (if you can find the relevant field, you will be able to see which products it's available in) you will need to speak to your Bloomberg rep about whether this data is available as part of the back office datalicense files.  I find the rep is the fastest way to get to speak to the relevant person for particularly complex questions.

Type `BREP` to see contact details for your rep.