# Error through RefreshAllStatisticData in VB

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, bloomberg

I have a similar problem to: [Bloomberg data doesn't populate until Excel VBA macro finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669845/bloomberg-data-doesnt-populate-until-excel-vba-macro-finishes)

I wanted to run my macro ConvertTocsv through a vb script file, to schedule it later. In my files are Bloomberg formulas, so I added Sub Master1 with RefreshAllStatisticData so the Bloomberg values can populate. When I run the macro Master1 from the excel it works fine. However, when I run it from the script file I get a run time error "1004".

Here is the code from the vb script file:

```
    dim objXL
    dim objWkb
    dim strPath

    strPath = "S:\Back Office\Tradar\Daily Report Files_Bloomberg\Custom_Daily_Report_BDP_20190807 with Macro_Template.xlsm"
    Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    objXL.Run "'" & objWkb.Name & "'!Master1"

    Set objWkb = Nothing
    Set objXL = Nothing
```

Here is the macro:

```
Sub Master1()
    Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "ConvertTocsv"
End Sub

Sub ConvertTocsv()

    Dim strfilename As String
    strfilename = "S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP\Custom_Daily_Report_BDP_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".csv"

    ChDir "S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        ("S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP\Custom_Daily_Report_BDP_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True, Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True    

    Information.Show

    returnvalue = Shell("notepad.exe " & strfilename, vbNormalFocus)

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

What is wrong? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Excel Macro from Outside Excel Using VBScript From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line)

Comment: Hi Miles, thanks for that. But is does not solve my issue.